# Reading from memory mapped register

Tags: c++, c, benchmarking, performancecounter

The processor architecture I am working with has a time tag counter that I wanna read out to make performance measurements. The time tag counter is memory mapped to the
address 0x90000008. I used the following routine to read the value from the time
tage counter, however the difference in the print out is always zero. Anyone an idea
what I am missing?

```
char* const ADDR = (char *) 0x90000008;

unsigned long cycle_count_val() {

   unsigned long res;

   asm volatile (

   "set ADDR, %%l0           \n\t"
   "ld [%%l0], %0            \n\t"

   : "=r" (res)
   :
   : "%l0"
  );

  return res;
} 

....
unsigned long start = cycle_count_val(); 
execute_benchmark();
unsigned long end = cycle_count_val();

printf("Benchmark performance(in clock cycles) = %ld \r\n", end-start);
```

Many thanks for your help,
Phil

Comment: Are you sure that your timestamp is a `char`?

Comment: no, it's a 30-bit value in a 32-bit memory location (MSBs are 0)

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you need to resort to assember - why can't you just read from:

```
uint32_t tbr = (*((uint32_t volatile *) 0x90000008))
```

Comment: just `#define` the whole expression as `now`.